# Does yield point of steel depend on thickness?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, steel, structures, yield-point

I have two different plates of different thickness and I need to calculate yield point. Does yield point of steel plate changes with changing of plate thickness?

Comment: Do we use thicker plates to increase the mass or to increase the strength?

Comment: What do you mean by "yield point"?  Stress at yield?  Applied load at yield?  Strain at yield?  Physical location on the plate that yields first?

Comment: are you asking if a 10 mm thick steel plate is as strong as a 10 cm thick one?

Comment: Yield strength actually can depend on thickness. Rolled steel plates have lower yield strength when thicker, because it is somewhat more difficult to control internal flaws at higher thicknesses. Anyway, the question could be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, "no", but here I qualify the answer:
If by yield point you mean 'at what loading will this steel plate yield', then it is  basically a tensile strength test result. This can be calculated by knowing the specified yield stress strength of the material (fy = ?) and the cross section area subjected to the yield strength (A).

T (at yield) = A * fy

If by yield point you are asking 'what is the yield stress of the steel plates of varying thickness, then it is the same equation, with fy as the unknown:

fy (at yield) = T / A

Manufacturing and fabrication of steel plate can cause localized stresses and material differences, but manufacturers and fabricators take measures to minimize those variations and provide a uniform product. I'm assuming that is beyond the basic question that you were asking.